# Replace defined words in a file with replacements in another file - Java

Tags: java, replace

I have a file (*file1.txt*) containing:

```
word word word2 word word1
word2 word word 1
```

The other file (*file2.txt*) contains:

```
word1-replacement1
word2-replacement2
```

I need a method looking up if the words from file2 are contained in file1 and if they are contained replace those words with the replacement.
I already have following:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file2.txt"));
    BufferedReader br2 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file1.txt"));
    String line;
    String line2;


    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        String vars[] = line.split("-");
        String varname = vars[0];
        String replacement = vars[1];

        while ((line2 = br2.readLine()) != null) {
            if(line2.contains(varname)) {
                line2.replace(varname, replacement);
            }
        }
    }
```

The problem with this code is, that it just reads only the first line of file1.

The final output should look like:

```
word word replacement2 word replacement1
replacement2 word replacement1
```

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: I'd probably read the file2 first and store all the replacements in some map. Then iterate over all the words in the file1 and replace them based on the content of the map. However, if those files are very big you probably have to think about some other approach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest first reading in the second file into Java memory, and storing the data as a key value store in a hashmap.  Then, iterate over the lines from the first file, and make any matching replacements.

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
String line = "";

try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file2.txt"))) {
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        String[] parts = line.split("-");
        map.put(parts[0], parts[1]);
    }
}
catch (IOException e) {
    // handle exception
}

try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file1.txt"))) {
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        for (Map.Entry< String, String > entry : map.entrySet()) {
            String pattern = "\\b" + entry.getKey() + "\\b";
            line = line.replaceAll(pattern, entry.getValue());

            // now record the updated line; printed to the console here for demo purposes
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    }
}
catch (IOException e) {
    // handle exception
}
```

Note carefully that I call `String#replaceAll` above with word boundaries around each term.  This matters because, for example, without boundaries the term `word1` would match something like `aword1term`, that is, it would match `word1` even as a substring of some other word.

Answer (score 0):

You can start by creating a Map of replacements like so:

```
public Map<String,String> getReplacements(File file) throws FileNotFoundException {
    Map<String, String> replacementMap = new HashMap<>();
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);
    while(sc.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = sc.nextLine();
        String [] replacement = line.split("-");
        String from = replacement[0];
        String to = replacement[1];
        replacementMap.put(from,to);
    }
    return replacementMap;
}
```

And then use the map to replace the words in the other file.